# Laravel files/folders not showing up in Public directory

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, webpack, laravel-8

I want to integrate TradingView's charting library in my Laravel project.
I have copied the charting_library folder to the Public folder of Laravel.
After that, I have referenced the charting_library.min.js file from Blade files in view and the other resources related to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('tradingview/charting_library/charting_library.min.js') }}">
```

All js files loads successfully, but **the problem** is that this charting_library.min.js calls an HTML file from a subdirectory where it returns a 404 Not Found error.

```
http://localhost:8000/charting_library/static/fa-tv-chart.37***ee.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is the file/folder structure: 
[image]
I have checked loaded resources from chrome's dev tools.
Laravel loads these referenced JS files, but it doesn't load any other files which these files have requested and just returns 404.
[image]
The charting_library folder exists in the directory, it's just something related to Laravel. I think it can't see the directory's contents.
I have tried to modify the .htaccess file but still no luck.
I even tried to mix charting_library.min.js via Webpack, changing autoload, but still, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried running your site over a local virtual host like apache?

Comment: So what is the URL of the JS library file? Can you access `http://localhost:8000/charting_library/static/fa-tv-chart.37***ee.html` in your browser? Why is a JavaScript file trying to access files with a non-relative URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by:

1. Moving the project to wamp's www folder.
2. Moving charting_library and datafeeds folder to the root of laravel's public. It seems
   tradingview's widget constructor uses relative path's for building
   whole chart. So when you place the charting_library inside a folder,
   it doesn't resolve other assets. These folders should be exactly in
   the root.

Comment: Thanks to @babak-ashrafi 's comment. It turned me to the right path.